# I want to hide table row of particular cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I have created a script which is for hiding a row that contain particular word, in my case that word is "active". Now the problem is the script only hiding first row and than it stops executing. so basically it works but after hiding first row, it stops executing.

any suggestions are welcome

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <table id="myTable">
     <tr id="my">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td >active</td>
        </tr>
     <tr  id="my">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  id="my">
            <td>4</td>
            <td>44</td>
            <td>inactive</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  id="my">
            <td>5</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>inactive</td>
        </tr><tr  id="my">
            <td>6</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  id="my">
            <td>7</td>
            <td>77</td>
            <td>inactive</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<script>
var oTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
var row = "active";
var count=0;
var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
//document.writeln("no fo row in table"+rowLength); 
    for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
    {
        var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
         var cellLength = oCells.length;
         //document.writeln(count);
         count=count+1;    
         for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++)
            {
                var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;     
            //  document.writeln("table values"+cellVal);
                 if(cellVal==row)
                     {
                                document.getElementById('my').style.display = 'none'; 
                                document.writeln("table values"+count+"<br/>");                             
                     }  
                else
                    {

                    }
                }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you give me a some hits for this....

Comment: You have invalid HTML; an `id` can be used only once. You should be using a class-name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, despite your having already accepted an answer:

```
$('#myTable tr').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('td:last-child').text().toLowerCase() === 'active';
}).hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bf949/).

With regard to your further question (in comments to another answer):

> Just one think can help me if there more then word like active,enable,disable i have to compare then how was code like

I'd suggest the following approach:

```
var states = {
    'active' : {
        'display' : 'none'
    },
    'inactive' : {
        'color' : 'orange'
    }
};


$('#myTable tr td:last-child').each(function(){
    var that = this,
        $that = $(that);
    $that
     .parent()
     .css(states[$that.text().toLowerCase()] || '');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bf949/2/).

Comment: this code works fine for static data, but the problem is my data is coming from database so, basically i want hide the dynamic data. is it possible to do?

Comment: Yes, but without more information I can't say how. You may want to post a new question about that aspect, including the relevant details.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myTable tr').each(function() {
    var st = $(this).find("td:last").html();    
    if(st!='active'){
    $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: just one think can help me if there more then word like active,enable,disable i have to compare then how was code like

Comment: this code works fine for static data, but the problem is my data is coming from database so, basically i want hide the dynamic data. is it possible to do?

Comment: dynamic data?? what to hide??